# RxJS - One observer waiting for multiple events

Tags: rxjs

I am trying to implement a pattern where I want to emit an event to all of a single observer's subscribers, and then wait until all of the subscribers respond. So "A" emits to "1", "2", and "3" (which all subscribed to it), and then processes the results once "1", "2", and "3" have all responded. The list of subscribers is dynamic (i.e. I don't know the number of them), but once added it won't be removed

Naturally, the second half of this is the difficult part, and I don't know how to implement it. The only thing I could come up with was having each subscriber send its own Subject to the main Observable service, and use a zip, but I much prefer a better solution.

My solution (in pseudo AngularJS):

Main.js:

```
function() {
    var subscribers = [];
    var subjectPublishingFromMain = new RxJs.Subject();
    var publishToMain = function(subject) {
        subscribers.push(subject);
    };

    var publishToAllAndDealWithResponse = function() {
        subjectPublishingFromMain.next(giveMeData);
        zip(subscribers).subscribe( 
            function(allTheData) {
            //Deal with all the subscriber data
        });
    };

    return {
        subjectPublishingFromMain: subjectPublishingFromMain,
        publishToMain: publishToMain
    };
}
```

Subscriber1.js

```
function(main) {
    var mySubject = new RxJs.Subject();
    var toMain = new RxJS.Subject(); 
    main.subjectPublishingFromMain.subscribe(
        function(fromMain) {   
            if(fromMain.type === 'INITIAL') {
                main.publishToMain(mySubject);
            }
            else() {
                mySubject.next(myData);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It's a bit confusing what you're trying to do and what this code does.`forkJoin` emits only when all its sources emit at least once and complete but you're not calling `mySubject.complete();` so this might be the problem.

Comment: Sorry, forkjoin is probably the wrong function. I want something that will trigger after all the subscribers emit a value (not oncomplete, just next)

Comment: Then maybe `zip` or `combineLatest` is what you're looking for. `zip` emit when all sources have emitted the same number of emissions.

Comment: Even with zip, is there a better pattern to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do. If you can make an isolated stackblitz demo of what you want to achieve that would be helpful.